# Remove/Hide elements specified in a xsl-fo file in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, xml, element, xsl-fo

In an xsl-fo file how can I remove some elements

Answer (score 0):

Quickest way, perhaps not the most elegant :

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

StringBuilder xmlSb = new StringBuilder();
xmlSb.AppendLine("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?>");
xmlSb.AppendLine("<fo:root xmlns:fo=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format\">");
xmlSb.AppendLine("  <fo:layout-master-set>");
xmlSb.AppendLine("    <fo:simple-page-master master-name=\"master\">");
xmlSb.AppendLine("      <fo:region-body margin-bottom=\"0.5in\" margin-top=\"0.9in\" margin-left=\"35pt\"/>");
xmlSb.AppendLine("      <fo:region-before region-name=\"xsl-region-before\" extent=\"0.9in\"/>");
xmlSb.AppendLine("      <fo:region-after region-name=\"xsl-region-after\" extent=\"0.5in\"/>");
xmlSb.AppendLine("    </fo:simple-page-master>");
xmlSb.AppendLine("  </fo:layout-master-set>");
xmlSb.AppendLine("  <fo:page-sequence master-reference=\"master\"/>");
xmlSb.AppendLine("</fo:root>");

// Load xml from string
xmlDoc.LoadXml(xmlSb.ToString());

Console.WriteLine("----- Original xml -----");

Console.WriteLine(xmlSb.ToString());

// Select region-before node
XmlNode regionBeforeNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//*[local-name()='region-before']");
// Remove region-before node
regionBeforeNode.ParentNode.RemoveChild(regionBeforeNode);

// Select region-after node
XmlNode regionAfterNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//*[local-name()='region-after']");
// Remove region-after node
regionAfterNode.ParentNode.RemoveChild(regionAfterNode);

Console.WriteLine("----- Nodes removed -----");

StringBuilder sbOut = new StringBuilder();
// Pretty indented output
XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings
{
    Indent = true,
    IndentChars = "  ",
    NewLineChars = "\r\n",
    NewLineHandling = NewLineHandling.Replace
};

using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(sbOut, settings))
{
    xmlDoc.Save(writer);
}

Console.WriteLine(sbOut.ToString ());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication11
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml = 
                "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?>" +
                "<fo:root xmlns:fo=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format\">" +
                "  <fo:layout-master-set>" +
                "    <fo:simple-page-master master-name=\"master\">" +
                "      <fo:region-body margin-bottom=\"0.5in\" margin-top=\"0.9in\" margin-left=\"35pt\"/>" +
                "    </fo:simple-page-master>" +
                "  </fo:layout-master-set>" +
                "  <fo:page-sequence master-reference=\"master\"/>" +
                "</fo:root>";

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
            XNamespace nsFo = doc.Root.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("fo");

            XElement regionBody = doc.Descendants(nsFo + "region-body").FirstOrDefault();

            regionBody.Add(new XElement(nsFo + "test", new object[] { new XAttribute("name", "John")}));
 

        }
    }
 
}
```

Comment: I am actually just trying to remove <fo:region-before region-name="xsl-region-before" extent="0.9in"/> from the <fo:simple-page-master master-name="master"> and I tried executing something like this..  doc.Descendants(nsFo + "xsl-region-before").Remove(); but it didnt work

Comment: I think you just had a typo in the tag name : doc.Descendants(nsFo + "region-before").Remove();  I was trying to help with your earlier posting that was deleted.  You can loop through your contents and add the document.